# Beanstalkd for CentOs 7

Tags: linux, beanstalkd, centos7, epel

Due to a misconfiguration I've migrated a VPS from CentOs 6 to CentOs 7 for a fresh start. Among other things I had a beanstalkd service installed on CentOs 6.

At the time I've followed this tutorial http://viewsfromtheside.com/2014/06/12/install-beanstalkd-centos-6/ and it worked perfectly for me.

But now, I can't install Beanstalkd on my CentOs 7 version.

I used those line for EPEL repo :

```
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm
```

Then I tried :

```
# yum install beanstalkd --enablerepo=epel-testing
```

and :

```
# yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" list available | grep 'beanstalkd'
```

and even :

```
#  yum search beanstalkd
```

But still : No matches found for: beanstalkd ...

I am new to CentOs and EPEL repos, so maybe I missed something ? Anyway, how can I install Beanstalkd on CentOs 7 ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can instal it via git and then copy systemd script:

**Step 0. Install git**

`yum install git`

**Step 1. Clone repository**

```
git clone git://github.com/kr/beanstalkd.git
cd beanstalkd
make
cp beanstalkd /usr/bin/beanstalkd
mkdir /var/lib/beanstalkd
```

**Step 2. Make startup script**

Create file `/etc/systemd/system/beanstalkd.service` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Beanstalkd is a simple, fast work queue

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/beanstalkd -b /var/lib/beanstalkd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step 3. Finally, run**

`systemctl enable beanstalkd` and `systemctl start beanstalkd`

**Step 4. Check**

`ps ax | grep beanstalkd`

Comment: run as nobody better? https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/adm/systemd/beanstalkd.service

Comment: worth mentioning for a clean server, packages gcc, git, make are all required

`yum install gcc git make`

Also if you do `make install` then copy to /usr/bin not needed as it installs to /usr/local/bin which would need changing in startup script

`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd -b /var/lib/beanstalkd`

Comment: Don't forget `systemctl daemon-reload` after you create the service file. Also, if you don't want the default 65335 bytes, you can add `-z BYTES` to the argument in the service file.

Answer (score 3):

1. yum install beanstalkd
2. service beanstalkd start
3. service beanstalkd status

Comment: anyone running standard centos7 this seems to work fine

Answer (score 2):

A request to publish a beanstalkd rpm package in EPEL for CentOS 7 has been made via https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1139358. You have to wait for the package maintainer to publish a package.

Meanwhile you can build your own package or download and install the RPM from http://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=686:

```
yum install http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/beanstalkd/1.9/3.el7/x86_64/beanstalkd-1.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build from source on Centos 7. Just git clone it:

https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd

Then make, make install as noted there.
This works but I could not daemonize it and could not find startup scripts for Centos 7.
Ended up just configuring it in supervisord to make sure it always runs.

Answer (score 0):

Four easy steps to install, enable on boot, start and check status for beanstalkd service on Centos 7:

- yum install beanstalkd
- systemctl enable beanstalkd
- service beanstalkd start
- service beanstalkd status